# Plotting at wrong position

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I need to plot my training set using Gnuplot, this is file with my **points** (x y coordinates):

```
0   0
100 100
150 200
```

Here is my **config** for gnuplot:

```
set terminal jpeg size picture_width,picture_height;
set output filename_output;
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
unset xtics;
unset ytics;
set multiplot
plot 'spirala.jpg' binary filetype=jpg with rgbimage
plot filename_input notitle lt rgb "#00FF00"
unset multiplot
```

This is how I **run** GnuPlot

```
gnuplot\gnuplot.exe -e "filename_output='output\plot_training_set_0.jpg'; \
filename_input='output\plot_training_set_0.txt'; \
picture_width=200; picture_height=200;" plot.cfg
```

And this is my result (unfortunatelly), **why there isn't markers at positions** [0, 0], [100, 100] and [150, 200]? There is only one marker at [133, 100] which is completely wrong.

[image: Plotted training set]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two independent plots, which are overlayed. Because you don't set explicit `xrange` and `yrange`, each plot does its own autoscaling. Just use a single `plot` call, without the `multiplot` mode, and you're fine:

```
set terminal jpeg size picture_width,picture_height
set output filename_output
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
unset tics

plot 'spirala.jpg' binary filetype=jpg with rgbimage,\
     filename_input notitle lc rgb "green"
```

Comment: I had to also reverse the y axe to have the [0,0] point in the upper left corner. So if anyone would need it too, use `set yrange [0:picture_height] reverse`